# PHP Apache module mod_evasive not blocking by IP only

Tags: php, apache2, whm, mod-evasive

I follow this tuorial and install mod_evasive

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Apache+Module%3A+Evasive#ApacheModule:Evasive-Configuration

```
<IfModule mod_evasive24.c>
  DOSHashTableSize    3097
  DOSPageCount        10
  DOSSiteCount        50
  DOSPageInterval     3
  DOSSiteInterval     4
  DOSBlockingPeriod   60
</IfModule>
```

I set setting `DOSBlockingPeriod` Block bad IP for 60 seconds. Its default setting was 10 seconds

If i refresh my website 10 times in 3 seconds, then i get 403 error, seems OK.

**Problem 1**

But after after 10 seconds or sometime before 10 seconds my website again start working, its not block my IP for 60 seconds.

---

**Problem 2**

For testing I send request 500 per seconds with different user agent, its not block my request. It is not protecting me from DDos with IP. If all request from same useragent then its block the IP.

If any IP block in 1 browser, it is working in other browser, thats mean mod_evasive block check IP+user_agent. I want to block a bad IP for 60 seconds.

I check answers those are 8 years old, and not a solution for me.

Centos 7, PHP 7.2, Apache 2.4

Any solution?